# Why does DynamoDB performance decrease with parallel reads?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

With AWS-XRay tracing enabled on my lambda function i've found that as the number of parallel requests increases to dynamodb the performance of the read's decreases.

Here is an example of the XRay Traces:
[image]

Above you can see that the first set of GetItem requests execute in under 300ms. This set only has 6 async read requests running in parallel. The next set of read requests all execute in on average atleast 1.5 seconds - with 57 async read requests running in parallel.

Thoughts on what this could be due to:

- this may be due to a "cold start" feature as dynamodb adds capacity to deal with parallel reads? (This dyanmodb instance is pay-by-request, not provisioned)

Additionally, i recognize that this may not be related parallel requests at all, but it may be a good place to start asking questions. Wondering if anyone knows what could be causing such a dramatic performance decrease.

Comment: Have you tried changing it to "On Demand" just to see if it behaves any differently?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the RAM of your Lambda function to see if performance improves? More RAM also adds more CPU and network resources. Also, nodejs is single threaded so there may be an issue with your code blocking?

Comment: @JaredHatfield the aws-sdk is asynchronous, meaning using promises/async-await will take care of the multi-threading out of the box, but indeed it could be that he's running in a low-profile machine which only has a couple of cores N, so essentially there are only N requests running simultaneously

Comment: 57 parallel async read requests from within a single lambda invocation?  Or 57 parallel/concurrent Lambda invocations, each making one request?

Comment: @JaredHatfield thank you for pointing that out! I've just increased the memory size from 265mb to 2048mb and that seems like it did the trick - all requests are now less than 200ms, even with the 50 parallel get requests! If you post that as the answer, I will accept it.

Comment: @ThalesMinussi thank you for the response - it seems like that was indeed the culprit! Increasing the size to 2048 resulted in each request taking ~200ms (down from 1.5s-2s).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot 57 parallel async read requests from within a single lambda invocation